# how to give custom margin for coverpage with wicked_pdf in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

i don't want margin for the fist page on generating PDF

this is the ruby code to generate the pdf

```
  def files
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: params[:filename],
               page_size: 'A4',
               dpi: '300',
               user_style_sheet: '../assets/stylesheet/quotation.css',
               margin:  {
                top:               0,
                bottom:            0,
                left:              0,
                right:             0
              }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers and footers and margins are global to the PDF created, so you can't tweak the cover page independently.

However, you can create two PDFs, one of just the cover, and one of the rest and combine them with Ghostscript or PDFtk.

```
html_content = render_to_string
cover_pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_content, { footer: { margin: { bottom: 200 })
body_pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_content, { footer: { margin: { bottom: 10 })

cover_src_temp_file = Tempfile.new(['cover_src', '.pdf'])
cover_src_temp_file.binmode
cover_src_temp_file.write(cover_pdf)
cover_src_temp_file.rewind
cover_temp_file = Tempfile.new(cover_pdf)
`pdftk #{cover_src_temp_file} cat 1 output #{cover_temp_file.path.to_s}` # first page only

body_src_temp_file = Tempfile.new(['body_src', '.pdf'])
body_src_temp_file.binmode
body_src_temp_file.write(cover_pdf)
body_src_temp_file.rewind
body_temp_file = Tempfile.new(body_pdf)
`pdftk #{body_src_temp_file.path} cat 2-end output #{body_temp_file.path}` # everything else

output_temp_file = Tempfile.new(['output', '.pdf'])
`pdftk #{cover_temp_file.path} #{body_temp_file.path} cat output #{output_temp_file.path}`
send_file output_temp_file, disposition: 'inline'

[cover_src_temp_file, body_src_temp_file, cover_temp_file, body_temp_file, output_temp_file].each do |tf|
tf.close
tf.unlink
end
```

Source - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/572#issuecomment-245044036